# how to duplicate whole project in VB

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Basic 2010 Express.

I tried to copy project folder and rename it to duplicate one of my project. But it acts like my old project. I tried change root namespace and assembly name but no luck.

How can I duplicate my whole project like "save as"?

Comment: @Ahmet vardar - in what way do you want it to act differently than your old project?

Comment: I don't get the "rename" bit, how would you copy a project folder without giving the new folder a different name?

Comment: for example, when my old app is opened, new one doesnt open (cuz i set the old one only 1 instance)

Comment: @nobugz of course you are right, it s because of my english, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+C  Ctrl+V the whole project folder.

After that try taking a look at the SLN file and see if the projects are being referenced with absolute paths.

Comment: @Ahmet: What do you mean by registrydata?

Comment: like this"Application.CommonAppDataRegistry.GetValue"